# last.fm API issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, last.fm

I am using `last.fm` `JavaScript` API (https://github.com/fxb/javascript-last.fm-api) for fetching similar tracks (track.getSimilar).

[last.fm API track.getSimilar response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlOYy.png)

```
success: function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.similartracks.track.length; i++) {
    alert("Track Name "+data.similartracks.track[i].name);
  }
}
```

How do I access small image URL?

I have tried `data.similartracks.track.image[0]` but it returns me [object 
Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to just comment apparently, but my only advice is: in your browser console open your object so you can more specifically access the field containing the url string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.
This worked for me
data.toptracks.track[i].image[3]["#text"] // In this case we are getting the 3rd Image URL.